# How to show an ellipsis as text inside a span element?

Tags: css, html, ellipsis

I have a requirement where I want to show ... as text inside a span. For some reason unknown to me, no browser seems to recognize it as a text. Is there something I am missing here?
I have jquery 1.8.3 included in the page if that makes any difference.

```
.ellipse{
    float: left;
 }    

var less = '<span class="ellipse less">...</span>';
var div = '<div></div>'


$(div).html(less);
```

I expect to see

```
<span class="ellipse less>...</span>
```

in the browser debugger. But what I see is

```
<span class="ellipse less></span>
```

The ... does not appear as text inside the span element.

Fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/P4J8u/12/

Comment: how do you add it to the page?

Comment: could you give us more details please, I personally don't really understand you problem...

Comment: I am trying to create a string which is a HTML - like the one in the question above. Later I use $(smthg).html(<include the string here>) to construct the html.

Comment: please specify why the down votes. Will let me know what I did not add to the question.

Comment: You need to include the jQuery that updates your html in your question.

Comment: Well, you don't give much details. What do you mean by "no browser seems to recognize it as a text"?

Comment: okay, your code-block is totally out of context. Split it up in CSS and JavaScript and give a little more context on the JavaScript - part, how should we know what `this` represents in your example?

Comment: I edited the question to post the exact code that replicates my issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/P4J8u/)

Here is a working example of "..." being added to a page.

```
var less = '<span class="ellipse less">...</span>';
$('body').html(less);
```

In you question, you made an edit to include, `$(this).html(less);`, but what other code do you have, because from that nobody knows what `this` is referring to.

Comment: I updated the fiddle you posted here to replicate my problem.

Comment: Thats cool, but you have to tell me the link, or I am going to sit here and guess?

Comment: You have to create the div element before appending html to it. You cannot just append html to an html string stored in a variable.

Comment: You have no `div` in your html. Do you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/watson/P4J8u/13/  ?

Comment: yes, I missed adding the div to the body in the  fiddle code.